# Setting an IdentityUserRole primary key - The entity type 'IdentityUserRole<Guid>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to extend the identity entities however am experiencing an issue with my entity which extends from `IdentityUserRole`, giving a runtime error of:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.'](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.%27) was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I've extended all identity tables:

```cs
public class AppRole : IdentityRole<Guid> { }

public class AppRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid> { }

public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid> { }

public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }

public class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }

public class AppUserToken : IdentityUserToken<Guid> { }
```

And my context is defined as:

```cs
public class AppDBContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : AppDBContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>(options)
{ }
```

The primary key for the `AppUserRole` table entity should consist of the two foreign keys pointing to the related tables, `UserId` and `RoleId`. This is the default primary key, however does not appear to be working when extending the `IdentityUserRole` table.

I've tried the suggestions in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key):

**Annotations dont work**

I have tried to specify this primary key using attributes, however this makes no difference (It seems like none of the common attributes are acknowledged on the identity tables, `TableAttribute`, `PrimaryKeyAttribute` etc).

```cs
[PrimaryKey(nameof(UserId), nameof(RoleId))]
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }
```

**Fluent API doesnt work**

I've also tried setting this via the fluent API in the `OnModelCreating` method, however again this doesnt seem to make any difference and I get the same error:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    this.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<AppUserRole>().HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
}
```

How can I specify the primary key for this table?

Interestingly, if I define my context with the default `IdentityUserRole` type, it works absolutely fine:

```cs
public class AppDBContext(DbContextOptions options, IConfiguration config)
    : AppDBContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid, AppUserClaim, IdentityUserRole<Guid>, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>(options)
{ }
```

For some reason, EF just isnt able to work out the primary key when extending the `IdentityUserRole` entity, and it seems to be ignoring my attempts to specify the primary key.

Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this works absolutely fine without having to manually specify the primary key, and my problem was occurring later while trying to seed data.

My seed process was trying to seed data using the base table type, rather than using my derived table types. The fix for me was to update the following:

```cs
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
    RoleId = 1,
    UserId = 1
});
```

With:

```cs
builder.Entity<AppUserRole>().HasData(new AppUserRole
{
    RoleId = 1,
    UserId = 1
});
```